# .htaccess rewrite to access php include in subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this URL that give me two main parameters, folder and page, and som other tahat can variable to be present or not:

```
http://www.domain.com/adm/master.php?f=folder&p=page&otherparam1=somthing&otherparm2=somthing&otherparm3=somthing[...]
```

in my master.php-file I include a php-file based on these parameters:

```
$folder = $_GET['f'];
$page = $_GET['p'];
if(empty($page)) {
    $page = 'dashboard';
}
$path = $folder.'/'.$page;
include_once 'pages/'.$path.'.php?otherparm1=somthing&otherparm2=somthing&otherparm3=somthing[...]';
```

The *otherparam* is to be multiple parameters given i the URL.

I want to rewrtite the URL to show somthing like this:

```
www.domain.com/adm/folder/page/somthing/somthing/somthing[...]
```

I have searched the web, but not been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with simple .htacces then you can use following .htacces code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|css|favicon.ico|fonts|images|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Basically what this code do is overwrite your request to your domain (ex: localhost/mysite), instead accessing folder or file it will access your `index.php`. Except for `index.php`, favoicon.ico, robots.txt files and css,fonts,image and js folder or what you define in second line on my code above.

Comment: Well, that is not the issue. OP is trying to rewrite a url with perameters to a diffrent destination , your code will send him/her to index.php

Comment: Oh, so that what he mean. I though he want to do url like this `www.domain.com/adm/folder/page/somthing/somthing/somthing` so i give him an example how to do it. Yes, it because i think it will send him to index.php so he can route it via index.php.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your Root/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^adm/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /adm/master.php?f=$1&p=$2&otherparam1=$3&otherparm2=$4&otherparm3=$5 [NC,L]
```

$1 ,$2,$3... contains whateve value was matched in regex capture groups "([^/]+)".

This will rewrite

```
example.com/adm/folder/page/foo/bar/foobar
```

to

```
 example.com/adm/master.php?f=folder&p=page&otherparam1=foo&otherparm2=bar&otherparm3=foobar
```

without changing the url in browser address bar.

Comment: When I type in the URL www.domain.com/adm/folder/page, I am redirected to www.domain.com/deltakere/legg-til... The "adm" is gone...

Comment: Are they real files or folders? I mean /adm/folder/page ?

Comment: Yes. The it is the path adm/folder/page.php

Comment: is your htaccess inside a subfolder? and Do you have any other rules in htaccess?

Comment: There was a .htaccess in the root, but I have deleted all other .htaccess files now, and it still don't work.